# Problem when baking the textures of the model, the textures become black or disappear

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

Then I was practising to be able to bake 3D models that I downloaded and mine too, but a problem has occurred that did not happen before and I do not understand now why it happens.

The 3D models to make bake suddenly textures apart that had nothing to do become completely black or disappear from one for no reason, also in the bake does not come out what I did but black or transparent

Why this happens and how to fix it? Is it due to Blender or something I did wrong?

I don't think it is the UV separator because they are separated from each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you provide more information this may help but here are common reasons :

1. Normals are flipped
2. There are no *Diffuse* or shaders connected to the material output
3. Baking image over already baked Image (to solve this pack it first)

There may be more reasons but this is the problems that I have encountered before